# Template Literal Type: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getResolvedBaseConstraint (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:53262:43)
    at getBaseConstraintOfType (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:53242:34)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:37)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
    at getTypeFacts (/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62711:24)
```

I have the following in `global.d.ts`:

```js
declare type UserId = `${number}`;
declare interface DevEnvironment {
  dev?: {
    user?: {
      userId?: UserId;
    }
  }
}
```

In the above interface, if I change `userId?: UserId` to `userId?: string`, then the above error goes away. I think it is because of this [template literal bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41651).

However, I am using the above like so; here I am building my environment file in my dev environment:

```js
let dev = {};
try {
  // The below file may or may not exists depending on the environment
  dev = require('./environment.local').dev;
} catch (e) { }

export const environment = Object.assign({}, {
  // Main environment variables
}, {dev: dev || {}} as DevEnvironment);
```

I then utilize it in a service:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class User {
  get userId(): UserId {
    const defaultValue = (environment.dev?.user?.userId || '000000000') as UserId;
  }
}
```

I know that the issue has said to have been fixed in newer versions of typescript, but we are stuck with `4.1.5` due to the usage of Angular 11 cli as seen here:

```
$ npm i typescript@^4.2.0
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.2.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=0.1000.0 < 0.1100.0" from @angular-builders/custom-webpack@10.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack
npm ERR!     dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack@"^10.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/rnaddy/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rnaddy/.npm/_logs/2021-07-08T15_28_45_346Z-debug.log
```

Is there something that I can do to use the syntax that I wanted to initially use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using typescript lower than 4 you get this error, upgrade to the latest one and chill))

Answer (score 0):

This is an [internal Typescript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1440) bug, for me production worked but not development.

Update typescript as suggested, even it's not exactly the same output it's the same problem.

I have no idea which version actually work, I ended up with 4.x.x it and magically work as expected.